# Returning the result after reading the csv file

Tags: node.js, express, papaparse

I am using PapaParse to read remote csv file and return the result, but every time it's empty not sure why.

```
function importData(url){
          const parseStream = Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {});
          let length = 0;
          const dataStream = request
              .get(url)
              .pipe(parseStream);
    
          let data: any[] = [];
          parseStream.on("data", (chunk: any) => {
              data.push(chunk);
    
          });
    
          dataStream.on("finish", (length) => {
              console.log(data);//this returns data
              console.log(data);//this returns data length
              length = data.length;
              return data;// Empty
          });
    
    return length;//Empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `return length` will be executed before the `dataStream`'s `finish`-event has been emitted. If you want your `importData` function to wait until this happens, you can wrap the parsing in a promise and wait until it's been resolved (still needs error handling, but should give you a start):

```
function importData(url){
    const parsePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const parseStream = Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {}); 
        const dataStream = request
            .get(url)
            .pipe(parseStream);

        let data: any[] = [];
        parseStream.on("data", (chunk: any) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });

        dataStream.on("finish", () => {                
            resolve(data);            
        });
    });
    return parsePromise
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data.length);
            return data;
        })
       
}
```

You can simplify this using `async/await`:

```
async function importData(url) {
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const parseStream = Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {});
        const dataStream = request
            .get(url)
            .pipe(parseStream);

        const data: any[] = [];
        parseStream.on("data", (chunk: any) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });

        dataStream.on("finish", () => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
    console.log(data.length);
    return data;
}
```